# MVC3 with EF Dbfirst, how to generate "controller with read write actions and views"

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am learning MVC3 and EF with DB first approach.

In some videos of MVC3 with code first approach from Scafolding Options they choosed **"controller with read write actions and views"** and after selecting Model and Data Context classes some code was automatically generated.

In my working I have a separate class library which has EF model in it **(please see blue selected area in diagrame)** . Please guide me how to access that EF and its generated classes to use with controller with read write actions and views ?

**EDIT**
I am adding new Controller.
I am not getting the comments you mentioned in your picture.
I am getting some classes in Model Classes drop down but not my EF classes are there in list.
I have not done any refrencing to class library in my MVC project. Please guie me how and what where to do ?

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're referring to [MVC Scaffolding](https://nuget.org/packages/MVCScaffolding)

```
Install-Package MvcScaffolding
```

If it shows No Model Classes availble, when you hover it will give you a more verbose description:

[image]

If you get this message, cleaning and rebuilding should fix your problem.

Is your database project referenced by your main project?  In your main project click references, add new reference - then in the projects tab select the name of the project with your edmx:

[image]

After that, clean and build!

Comment: thanks @Mark Oreta, I can see MvcScaffolding options but I am not getting to select classes (Model and db context). My EF model's classes are not appearing in lists ? can u plz help a little more. Thanks

Comment: My EF model is in another class library.

Comment: Have you built the entire solution?  The MvcScaffolding won't pick it up until the .dll's are in the right place.  You might try cleaning/rebuilding the solution

Comment: thanks again. I am sorry for my poor drawing. Can you please see image in question and see my Edit and guide ?

Comment: I added its refrence and in Model classes list was able to see "PracticeDBEntities (ClassLibrary.DAL)" but not individual classes. I want to use classes in EF to be used a Model without duplicating them. Please guide.

Comment: is it not possible to reference EF's generated classes as model in MVC application while EF model is in another class library. I also dont want to duplicate classes by generating them again in Model but want to keep my EF in seprate class library ? please advice.

Comment: I'm looking at your image, and I see a class of ChangePassWordModel, and then I also see that in the dropdown - is that not the EF generated class?  If it's not, can you take a screenshot w/ your edmx opened so I can see what was generated (you are using an edmx correct? if not, can you post the code first model)

Comment: Oh I m very sorry Mark Oreta, tables were not added into EF Model. I opened model added tables and then EF classes were appearing in Modle drop down list.

But there is another issues (I am sorry to causing you this please).

I selected EF's generated class and also selected same class as a DataContext Class but it gives error/ warning "unsupported context type" can you please guide on this as well.

Thanks a lot for helping me and your precious time.

Comment: please also comment is it a standart way how I am thinking to do it (using other class library's EF generated classes without duplicating them into MVC application) ?

Comment: In the second box (Data context class), when you're creating the context be sure you select your model - it should end in Entities (in my example it was MyDatabaseEntities) [See this other SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9116601/mvc3-add-controller-scaffolding-error-unsupported-context-type)